# Clarification of decision tree surrogate splits

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rpart

I have a question regarding the output of an rpart classification tree in R. Where there is missing values, a surrogate split is used. Here is an example.

```
  Surrogate splits:
  ##       bmi    < 21.51 to the right, agree=0.858, adj=0.632, (0 split)
```

Is the agreement calculated as, the proportion of cases where the surrogate split agrees with the primary split? For instance, if the surrogate fails to agree on only 1 of 4 datapoints the agreement will be .75. Is this correct?

Furthermore, I am not certain on my interpretation of adj. Is this adjusted agreement, taking into account agreement by chance? If so how is this calculated? I think it must be something to do with the priors in the data but am unsure.

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the agreement calculation. adj is decrease in node impurity. It's with reference to the primary split of the rpart. The higher the adj, the better it is for the surrogate split to be considered. This is what my understanding is. It'd be grand, if anyone added to this.

Comment: If there are more than one surrogate split. Do they belong to the same most important primary split or are they the surrogate of the second most important primary split variable and so on?